# Flutter Navigator popUntil method doesn't stop at the Named Route I want it to, and pops all the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I have this bit of code that I want to pop all screens until it gets to the base screen with Name "/".

```dart
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/"));
```

Before I call the popUntil method, I navigated using:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Loading");
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/Menu");
```

But the result I'm getting is all the screens are getting popped until it gets to the black screen. What should I change to make it stop at "/"?

Here is how it's set up:

main.dart

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        onGenerateRoute: AppRouter().onGenerateRoute,
        initialRoute: '/',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppRouter {
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoadingScreen());
      case '/Menu':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MenuScreen());
      case '/Loading':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LoadingScreen());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ModalRoute.withName`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/withName.html) predicate is used when a route is tied to a specific route name. Because you're using [`onGenerateRoute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html) (which is typically a last resort) instead of the [`routes`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/routes.html) table in your `MaterialApp` there is no route associated with the `/` route name.